MySQL solution for many to many associative table that scale over billion entries
Scenario
Imagine we have a table user and an item user.
These 2 tables have an associative table called user_item to define a many to manyrelationship.

We start 100 item records

We have 500 Millions user records.

Therefore we must generate 50_000_000_000 user_item (50 billions)

We could potentially have even more

Won't be easy to shard nor partition because then, it will slow down any other operation (otherwise we need to scan everything)

Assume as query pattern (INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE) basic/typical m2m patterns (that could be found in any tutorial or example


Question
What's the best design or known solution for handling billions of Many to Many relationship in a database regardless of a schema?
Schema
Imagine this simple schema
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `playground` CHARACTER SET = latin1;
USE playground;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user`
(
    `id`   BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `user__name_fk` (`name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1
  ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item`
(
    `id`   BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `user__name` (`name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1
  ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_item`
(
    `user_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `item_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `item_id`),
    INDEX `user_item__item` (`item_id`),

    FOREIGN KEY `user_id_fk` (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY `item_id_fk` (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1
  ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;

-- create some default items
INSERT INTO `item` (`name`) VALUES ('item_1'), ('item_2'), ('item_3'), ('item_4'), ('item_5'), ('item_6'), ('item_7'), ('item_8'), ('item_9'), ('item_10');
-- create some users
INSERT INTO `user` (`name`) VALUES ('user_1'), ('user_2'), ('user_3'), ('user_4'), ('user_5'), ('user_6'), ('user_7'), ('user_8'), ('user_9'), ('user_10');
INSERT INTO `user_item` (`user_id`, `item_id`) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10);


More info
I'm not asking on how to use many to many relation ship in MySQL, i know that.
I'm asking what is the more known solution for a scaling issue, that is, when number of related records are exponentially growing to such big scale.
Also I intentionally didn't add any query pattern (INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE) because is irrelevant. Assume the most/typical M2M pattern. I don't want to loose focus on the real question which is about scaling and huge amount of data.
There must be some trick or some known workaround right?
I'm also considering a NoSQL database so the answer could include anything non related to MySQL (or any SQL databases),
I feel like this should be a common issue that many big company will face and hence there should be a common (or few) solution.
The root cause of this issue is that, while MySQL is great to create relationship, it will grow associative m2m table exponentially.
The 500 Millions x 100 == 50 Billions is just an example.
But could theoretically happen.
Clarification

I left query out in purpose because you can assume to most easy one.
I'm sure if I gave few example, will start to pop optimization over the specific query, that's not the question
I'm asking a very high level question, and if there is not a real known solution then a no with explaining why would suffice (assuming is correct)

Here an example of a simple many to many query..
SELECT user.*, item.* FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_item ON user.id = user_item.user_id
LEFT JOIN item ON item.id = user_item.item_id
WHERE user.name = 'user_1';

Similar but not same questions

Best design for a many:many relationship issue
Design a many-to-many table for scale
Many Many to many relationships databse design with MySql
better database design for nested relation (many-to-many-to-many?)


I don't get your question, as you're not providing the relevant information: At these scales every data access path needs to be carefully designed and optimized for. But you're not giving any information on what query patterns to expect.

@Grimaldi I mean i provided the schema and pretty clear bullet list point didn't I :D The query pattern can be expected as any basica Many to many relationship query. There are no example because is irrelevant. Take any many to many tutorial will do  and I didn't add them because indeed irrelevant and would look focus on the question. The question is: About SCALE and large amount of m2m .

The contents of a WHERE clause is very relevant to performance.  Fetching one row with an exact value will be fast if the indexing is good; fetching with OR or RLIKE leads to a table scan -- thereby being as slow as the table is big.

The query pattern is not irrelevant.  It is critical.  If you want to design a totally generic M2M table that handles all use cases, you don't have many better general options.  But when you're trying to scale a real system, you can make all sorts of optimizations because you know the important use cases.  Most OLTP queries in most real systems are going to drive based on one side of the M2M relationship almost exclusively so you can shard based on that key.  And you can create alternate structures if you need to optimize other workloads.

I think you guys are missing the point of the question. I am asking on the design or any solution (can be use a specific schema or even use a different database) instead you aee going ahead and thinking on the query. I wrote that you can assume the most simple query type (insert, select and delete). Not sure what you achieve on seen such query since are so common. If there isn't a better design (schema) to this problem or another type of database is necessary so let be that the answer. Obviously query are critical TO THE APPLICATION but irrelevant of THE QUESTION

I can add some query example tomorrow if this helps but again, I don't think is necessary. I asked if there is a known solution for this problem.

@FedericoBaù - There is no "one-size-fits-all".  I added to my Answer.

My missive on  Many-to-many

Note that for generating (and consuming) the cross product, a simple select … from a, b probably is going to be more efficient.

@Grimaldi - You never want to do a CROSS JOIN, especially not when the result set is 50B rows.  So, the Optimizer will look at the WHERE and ON clauses to avoid doing that.  [Hence the repeated plea to the OP for the queries that will be run.]

@RickJames Sure, but in the extremely unlikely case you need a cross join, it‘ll be more efficient than materializing it out in a M2M table. (And I was the first asking for clarification and query patterns :D)

Ok I'll mark my answer as accepted but if another more complete answer comes out in the future I can change it, I really don't care, important is the most correct/complete answer to my question.
My question has been greatly misunderstood and went in all different direction (except Andrea B. one).
However, especially thanks to the 'conversations' in the comments, some part of the answer comes up, so if we combined comments + pieces of answer I think we can answer properly.
I don't mark Andrea B. answer though because after learning it I've a more complete answer.

So how can we solve a possible table, in this case ManytoMany - Associative table (which by nature is the easiest to grow in size compared to others).
We can assume that the schema its self is well designed at its maximum (column datatype etc) as well as query patterns (SELECT, INSERT ...) imagine/assume they have been already optimized to the maximum and there is really no better way to do them.
And is someone reading this answer is unsure, can go have a look at this guide of Many-to-Many by Rick James, is pretty cool I think.
But in your case, imagine you also know the rows of this table will grow exponentially, and soon or later will go over billions, what do you do?
First of all, it seems there isn't accepted way or 'technique' that works all the time so all below solution may or may not work (a.k.a are all workarounds) .
Among all 'solution' is seems that they have all 1 thing in common, there are basically some form of:
Divide-and-conquer algorithm
In other words, you need to find a way split the data as much as possible to make it more manageable. But in the same time, don't split too much because you may end up on a worst position, for instance, you need to being able to still retrieve SELECT data in a fast way, so keep in mind to avoid 'scanning' all this 'divided' 'part' (here I am still talking in a very high level and is an abstract idea, I'm not talking in anything in specific!)
Here are the techniques

Split data on the WHERE clause
Split data on the INDEX
Split data on usage | the 'Archive' concept
Sharding

Split data on the WHERE clause
This is the most obvious one and pretty basic, but may not work for all queries or sometimes you really need to find something and require to scan 'all data'. Obviously here comes along the LIMIT and OFFSET and all good practices.
Also, copied paste from comments (sorry I would link comment if was possible)

The contents of a WHERE clause is very relevant to performance. Fetching one row with an exact value will be fast if the indexing is good; fetching with OR or RLIKE leads to a table scan -- thereby being as slow as the table is big


You never want to do a CROSS JOIN, especially not when the result set is 50B rows. So, the Optimizer will look at the WHERE and ON clauses to avoid doing that. [Hence the repeated plea to the OP for the queries that will be run.]

Split data on the INDEX
Taken from J.D. Answer on the
Finale (after talking about bricks) is actually pretty interesting.
I won't add what he wrote to avoid repetition so you should check out that answer but the technique is true. While I personally know it I think is different if you think it in that way and have that explanation in mind.
Really we are just using indexing to split 'data population', Divide-and-conquer.
Split data on usage | the 'Archive' concept
Use Least recently used (LRU) for instance

An example of "access pattern" is News articles. Most people search for "recent" articles -- the articles on the current hot news topics. This tends to bias queries toward the "end" of the table. This can be helped by LRU and by clustering on date.

So this may not work for all cases for sure but, if you can implement a logic where basically, you avoid access all data if you know is 'old' or less used. Here may be different ways to achieve this

bias queries toward the "end" of the table with a DATETIME column (probably) - (or could be even id bigger than <VALUE> etc..
What if you can move 'all data' into a separate table (or database) and is access only when requested or the data you are looking for is not there.

For the second point, for instance, if you recognize a pattern in the data where, lots of data (maybe even most) is not accessed anymore you could move that (or rename the table) into another one ( user_item_archive ) then you create a new user_item and work on the fresh one. This is oversimplified and depends on use case but the important is the concept.
I'm pretty sure there are articles online about this concept, if someone finds any (or if I will in the future) we could add here.
Sharding
This is the only 'well known' technique but it's a double-edged sword for sure.
This blog on percona is very interesting
Someone mention partition, but I don't recommended because it as IMO little to none use cases and I see it more for when you need to delete data. Accessing data with partition already may lead to a lot of trouble.
Furthermore from this answer by Rick James while the first part tries to optimize the schema example (which is good but it was just an example) The last 2 bits are interestings IMO

Sharding may be useful when you have so much data that writing becomes a problem. However, the setup and maintenance is a hassle.


When you get into terabyte-sized tables, you should compute how long it will take to fill up the table. 50 billion rows, even if batched, could take weeks or months. A hardware RAID controller could help a little


If you don't understand one simple question nor you get it from the context of my accepted answer then my friend i really think you need to revisit a bit your self. The context of the problem was very specific yet not relative to a particular issue. Sometimes is needed to go deep some other is not and you just want the general how-to. I give an example with bricks since you like them. Imagine you need to transport 100tons of bricks and you ask some bricklayer whats typical transport or method, instead of tell you "a track or lorry would do or a company takes care of it...simple no?

"instead of tell you "a track or lorry would do or a company takes care of it...simple no?" - Nope. They would ask you "do you care about cost or speed of delivery?" to understand what problem you're trying to solve. And that's considering your brick transport example isn't one-to-one with your Post, not to mention transporting bricks is a much simpler scenario than database development. So despite all of that, without knowing what problem you're trying to solve, no one can give you a satisfactory answer. Case closed bud, no matter what you say to avoid the question.

Simply put, there is no general answer to the question of "what's typical for a large table?" because a large table isn't a problem by itself. And Sharding is definitely not typical. As I mentioned in my answer, I worked with a table of the size you originally asked about, and all we used was indexing to solve the problem of performance which had to do with specific queries. But since you don't want to say if you're asking about a performance problem or not, or give any specifics on what problem you're trying to solve, then no one can answer you.

Yet you are wrong J.D. you read my answer right? There is more than one way. But in the same time the second correct answer is Andrea B. Where he is more negatively telling me "there isn't a specific way". And yes there are general known things one can do for a generic problem.  Then if you go deep into details obviously the requirements or solution my change. For instance one could ask "how do company distribute load on servers evenly" and one could say "normally load balancer with round-robin, nginx etx.." no? You guys need to let it goo to many strict rule in you head. Think freely

"And yes there are general known things one can do for a generic problem." - Yes, no one disagreed about that. But you haven't provided any problem yet, so with no problem there are no solutions. For one last time, by itself, a large table is not a problem. Just like having a large amount of bricks is not a problem, in of itself.

J.D. i think i now understand and can explain the issue that you and others have here (with undoubtedly large experience in this field). I think you are too used on work at low level and everything shlould be seen at that perspective in your view. But it isnt. Imagine a dermatolog would always seen the skin and examine skin issue with his own eyes. A microbiologist instead would always work with a microscope. Both solve problems but at different levels. While one dont see the bacteria the other dont see the whole skin rash. But both may be right from their point of view.

Sure, but again, a person who has freckles doesn't have a problem and a microbiologist would still listen to the dermatologist on their input regarding that (instead of insisting they have a skin problem). Just like a large table is not a problem in itself, and you should listen to those more experienced than you about that. No matter what say you doesn't change that, objectively. Again and again, any example you give as an analogy fits the framework of what I'm saying and proves my point.

Preface
I think you're unfortunately misunderstanding:

How databases work at their core level, and
What some of the people of this community have been trying to communicate to you in regards to that.

Hopefully this answer helps clarify that.
I'll preface this by saying I have worked with large tables (~1 TB big) that had 10s of billions of rows in them, with queries that typically ran in under 1 second, on very modest hardware (4 CPUs, 16 GB of RAM).
I will also point out that size of data at rest is not a reason for choosing a specific database system, as they all handle the same amount of data relatively equally from a performance perspective (regardless if you're talking about NoSQL databases or RDBMS).
Data Organization
X amount of data is always going to take Y amount of time to read off disk. For example, in a 100 GB table, 1 GB of data is always going to take a consistently constant amount of time to read from the disk, it doesn't matter which database system is being used to store that data. Similarly to how a pickup truck can transport 100 bricks from one place to another, it doesn't matter what color that pickup truck is, it'll still take a consistent amount of time to transport the bricks.
The timesuck is locating the bricks that the customer wants to transport from the pile of all bricks (the table). If a customer wants 100 red bricks, and the bricks are all stored in one large unorganized pile on the ground (an unindexed Heap data structure), among 10 different colors, locating those 100 red bricks is going to take a long time to sort through all of the bricks to find.
Enter Indexes
Indexes are a feature (that almost every database system offers) as a way to organize the data in an efficient data structure for searching (generally a B-Tree by default). An index sorts the data in the table on the order of the columns specified in its definition, which then sorts related data together making it much more efficient to search than an unorganized heap table.
So if we apply an index to our random pile of bricks, let's say by color, then all the red bricks will be stacked next to each other, then the blue bricks all together, then the yellow bricks all together etc. Now instead of having to dig through the entire unorganized pile of all bricks, we can just walk directly to the red section and grab the first 100 bricks we can grab. This is obviously significantly more efficient than having to aimlessly search through all bricks.
The same is true for how data is organized in a table in a database. If the appropriate indexes are created on that table, then those indexes can be directly seeked on to the rows that correspond to the query that is asking for those rows, instead of having to scan through the entire table.
Why The Queries Are Relevant
I'll re-state what I just said above with some emphasis:

If the appropriate indexes are created on that table, then those indexes can be directly seeked on to the rows that correspond to the query that is asking for those rows

And a reminder on how indexes work:

An index sorts the data in the table on the order of the columns specified in its definition...

So in order for an index to be effective and helpful for a particular query, it needs to be defined appropriately based on the columns specifically used in that query.
In my example earlier about bricks, color was the field being searched on. If we sorted the bricks by color (defined the index by color) and the customer wanted bricks by size instead, then the index we created doesn't help us. This is akin to the WHERE clause in a query. Knowing what queries are most commonly ran, even more importantly what predicates (JOIN and WHERE clauses) those queries use, helps us define the most appropriate indexes to serve those queries.
It all goes hand-in-hand, and it's almost impossible to talk about performance in practice without talking about the queries you specifically want to perform well.
Another reason why knowing what queries will be most important to optimize for is because it may influence your table design and architecture. And there are other reasons as well, but all too many to go through in depth in one answer here. So I'm sticking to the most important one (in my opinion) to this discussion, and which is indexes.
Finale

I suppose somehow you gotta have to 'split' the data.. and there is no much else solution am i wrong?

Yes and no. You are right about the data being split but you are wrong in how you're thinking you have to do that, with Partitioning or Sharding. These aren't the right tools for this generalized discussion of performance tuning, and are only used for very specific purposes. Instead, you want Indexes again, which do split the data for you in how it's organized in that underlying data structure, again, a B-Tree.
B-Trees have an O(log2(n)) search time complexity with the way they organize data. That means in a table with 50 billion rows in it, aka n = 50 billion, the search time is log2(50 billion) = ~36. In other words, to seek on a B-Tree index against a table with 50 billion rows, only 36 of them need to be crawled to locate the data you asked for, in the worst case scenario. My graphing calculator can search through 36 rows of data in milliseconds.
As you can see, managing data to be searched for efficiently, is a solved problem, unlike you originally thought.

It is more like O(log100(n)) on the assumption that about 100 rows are found in each node of a BTree.  So, n=50 billion will hit about 5 nodes. For such a large table (or index), that could be 5 disk reads.  Disk reads cost more than looking for 1 item out of 100..  On spinning disks, one read ~=10ms; on SSD, ~1ms each.  Caching (buffer_pool) avoids some or all of the reads

A full table scan of 100GB is much slower if the blocks are not cached.

@JD I think you are still mis the question and lost the answering into talking about bricks. Did you read properly the question? Didn't you see the schema I provided? You wrote about bricks and indexs (which is intereting info still) but...didn't you see the schema which has index all over the place? The question could be simply asked without any schema what's so ever. For now, the only person that really answered the question more closely is https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/340022/222739 . The partitioning and sharding was just an example of 'possible technique

Comment continue: So partition let's forget about it , was an example and I know is used in few cases, same for sharding (but has a wider range) . You focus too much on what the data would look like or not. As I stated above, the question could have been asked with no schema nor query whats so ever. Expierience is good but I think sometimes it blocks with 'too much' and over complicate stuff. Don't take me wrong the 'Finale' part is very interesting but is still not what i'm asking. you are trying to 'prematurely optimize'

@FedericoBaù It's not premature optimization, it's showing you that the question you ask about is a solved problem in practice, when there's specifics. If you don't want to talk specifics, then there's only so much to talk about which has already been communicated to you. Regardless of what kind of conversation you want to have, all of the information has already been provided to you, and you would be wrong to say it's not a solved problem. Cheers!

@RickJames "It is more like O(log100(n))" - Yes, depending on database system, this is true. For simplicity's sake I just always refer to the generic log2 and talk in absolute worse case numbers to communicate that even in the absolute worst case, it's a trivial amount of processing that needs to occur. Thanks!

@J.D. the statement about  "not a solved problem" (which I wrote in some comment I belive but you took out of context right now) was about the fact that "It seems there isn't a 'technique or way to solve this problem, data will grow and that's it" But was based on fact that no one is giving a straight forward answer. Why you think I ask the question? was a conclusion based on answers.  Now in your answer it seems that you are writing as 'solution': "Split data based on index key" .. so why you simply don't answer that more clearly? Also, still is not always possible in effectively way is it?

@FedericoBaù Unfortunately I'm unclear on what you're unclear on. If you're saying that a table with a lot of data will have a lot of data and continue to grow, yes, that's true, but that's not a problem in itself. So it's unclear what you think is a problem and are referring to as unsolved. Everyone else here has been commenting on what would be a performance problem and what tools and information you would use to solve it (e.g. indexes catered to the queries for the data). But a large table with 50 billion rows by itself is not a problem.

Ok J.D. thanks. I ll wait till tomorrow w to see if more answer coming in. Then i ll take a decision on the answers given (plus comments)

@FedericoBaù Cool beans. I'm forced to assume by your lack of reply that you now understand what you did not previously. Cheers!

I am a fast learner yes XD

The best solution for your problem is what you already designed.
That's because all RDBMS are designed to handle exactly that: a bunch of tables, with many-to-many relations, and potentially billions of rows, where you SELECT, INSERT, or DELETE rows.
Any "special" storage system, like NoSQL, columnar storage, partitioning, etc. is useful only when you have "special" needs and your usage patterns are no more generic.
But for all OLTP and OLAP normal processing of data in a database, the schema you provided, is typical because it's the best one to solve the problem in absence of more specific characterics of data or usage patterns.
If you need to access a few rows at a time, you need indexes, and you have all the needed ones.
If you need to access a great percentage of data, nothing is more efficient than a full scan.
More optimization is possible only when your data is no more "generic", but displays some particularities (in the composition, or in the access pattern) that can be optimized with some tweaking, but as long as you don't have this particularities, there are no optimizations possible and scaling is not a problem, because RDBMS are designed exactly for this task.
Of course, the response will be slower when there are billions of records, but there is no general way you could store those billion of records in a more efficient way, if you have the typical access pattern.

Thanks, so it seem it's as I thought. I leave the question open for few days more but if there isn't a better answer than you are correctly answering what I'm asking so I'll accept it . Anyways is weird to me that there isn't a more known solution to this problem. I did check other Database paradigm but NoSQL for instance won't work (since I need proper relations etc.) and graphs (seems to what I found out) will not inbcrease performance at this number of records (furthermore, graph really are useful when yuou need relation->relation->relation... but relation->relation SQL should be better..)

@FedericoBaù that's because this is an age old problem, which existed since the first time someone wanted to use a computer to record and process data. RDMBS were invented to solve exactly this problem.

Sure but doesn't look like this age old problem has been solved (without some custom /weird trick) I mean, is all fun and games till you hit very large amount of data. the only (custom) solution I see is somehow to 'split' it .. if you lucky and you can. Sure some very smart dev have solved this in some cool way in different company but again, seems there is  no a standard way to do it (for instance at this point I just thought.. you can use some cache like on Least recently used (LRU) style  and leave alone some data that is never retrieved or something.. anyways ok

A "few rows at a time" is as slow as a table scan if OR, IN is involved.  [There are exceptions.]

An example of "access pattern" is News articles.  Most people search for "recent" articles -- the articles on the current hot news topics.  This tends to bias queries toward the "end" of the table.  This can be helped by LRU and by clustering on date.

@RickJames I would like to suggest that on OLAP, which is usually optimizing for read loads (as in write once, read many), materializing out both directions of the M2M relationship (partitioned) would be the way to go. But as Frederico asked for CRU(D), I agree. So +1.

@Grimaldi - Note that I recommend ( Many-to-many ) having covering indexes in both directions on the M2M table.  (And get rid of id.)  I don't understand what you mean by "partitioned".

@RickJames Sorry, I believe that‘s not available in InnoDB: Partitioning is chopping up a table into smaller tables with separate indices on a certain condition like storing user names A-D, E-K, K-… (you get the picture) into separate tables. Can speed up certain operations.

@Grimaldi - "Partition pruning" (as you alluded to) is akin to having an extra level in a BTree.  So, it is unlikely to be any faster, and is likely to be a little slower.  Partitioning may be beneficial when the index is really 2-dimensional:  Partition by range of (a) then filter on range of (b).  See lat-lng example:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng

This is a great question, but there's not a simple answer - particularly with the "ignore query pattern and schema/relationship".  Those two are needed if you are aiming at optimizations to help you scale.   Would love to know more about that.    The "NoSQL to help scale" has proven to many to be a non-answer.   If the data is relational (absolutely if it's transactional and relational) you will end up compensating for the nature of the things the NoSQL database concedes  in your app layer.   NoSQL databases as a category  relax consistency and transactional correctness and often abandon the relational model.  Re-implementing these in your application can be as complex (in some cases more complex) as the question of "how do I scale the database layer".   That said - there are good answers for this pattern in the NewSQL world.   I want to acknowledge I have a bias - I work for a database startup (Regatta) that has built a transactional, relational database that scales to hundreds and thousands of nodes, PB of data, trillions of records, and millions of TPS with strict serializability and external consistency.  Oh, and we can do analytics directly on that data too.   This has been viewed as an unsolvable problem, so people have often started with abandoning transactional/relational properties to scale out, or just accept sharded islands.   Would love to talk to you about it, and put us through out paces - we were built for this!

Finally, someone that answer the question :D


Since there are only 100 items...  If there won't be a lot more items, change to SMALL UNSIGNED (max of 65K).  This will save 30GB.  (Shrinking a table --> less I/O and better caching --> maybe better query performance.)

Consider having the item VARCHAR(..) in user_item instead of needing theitemstable.  If the strings are usually "short", the cost of the extra space will be offset by avoiding an extra lookup.  [I did this quite successfully withpicture_idandtag`.]

50 billion rows is not a serious problem if you are always using one of the indexes.

Consider INT UNSIGNED for user_id -- it will save 4 bytes over BIGINT, but is limited to 4 billion.  Check SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM user to see if you are [for whatever reason] already getting into the billions.

"otherwise we need to scan everything" -- What query is causing a big scan?

Is ON DELETE CASCADE important?  [This may not matter.]

PARTITIONing is useful for deleting old data, but not for performance of SELECTs.

Sharding may be useful when you have so much data that writing becomes a problem.  However, the setup and maintenance is a hassle.

When you get into terabyte-sized tables, you should compute how long it will take to fill up the table.  50 billion rows, even if batched, could take weeks or months.  A hardware RAID controller could help a little.



Thanks for the answer, I updated the questionso that we could have 100 items (my bad) so we could potentially let's say have 50 billions. for the ON DELETE CASCADE no necessaraly but. can you explain why you asked ? (I suppose could be a potential problem so ... what is it?)

"otherwise we need to scan everything" I meant. one way to possibly improve this is if, we have a way to shard this data in a logic way (like separate databases ) or partition but I know be a good solutuin because. let's say i want to list all user having item_x . i would need to scan 'all shard' . i hope is more clear?

Anyways, sorry I don't want to bombard with comments but. While the few bullet points are very valuable already, feels like.. .are all slightlly improvements on the schema. which again is good but feel like.. there isn't a 'known' way to solve this problem? I suppose somehow you gotta have to 'split' the data.. and there is no much else solution am i wrong?

look what i found XD https://stackoverflow.com/a/35532537/13903942
